# Regex for finding matches (plural) between two strings

Tags: c#, regex

I'm basically looking to restrict the search to just a particular section of a string. I can't tell if this is possible with regular expressions, but I haven't yet found anything that says it ISN'T possible! The posts I turn up are either situations I'm finding hard to extrapolate to my use, or they fall back on non-regex functions to accomplish the job.

An general example of what I mean is:

**Given the entire text of a book**, return all instances of *the* between *Chapter 1* and *Chapter 2*.

The above example is not my intended usage, but I'd like to ask in a general way so future generations can easily apply any answers to their own goals.

My goal is in use with the C# Regex.Replace function. I want to provide it the entire string, and have it replace matches from just a specific portion of the string.

I can of course do this by splitting apart the string, feeding just the relevant section to Regex.Replace, and then re-assembling it with a StringBuilder. But I don't want to do that if it's possible to achieve this with purely regular expressions.

Here is some example input for this situation, with the desired matches in bold:

*Prologue the following story is there for you to read Chapter 1 **the** quick brown fox jumped over **the** lazy dog Chapter 2 the dog died Chapter 11 don't ask about the missing chapters Chapter 21 the end*

Comment: post the expected output.

Comment: Added example input with desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the .NET regex engine allows for indefinite repetition in [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), making this possible:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(?<=\bChapter 1\b.*)\bthe\b(?=.*\bChapter 2\b)", "ye", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=           # Assert that it's possible to match this before the current position:
 \bChapter 1\b # the text "Chapter 1" (but not "Chapter 11")
 .*            # followed by any number of characters.
)              # End of lookbehind assertion.
\bthe\b        # Match "the" (but not "there" or "lathe").
(?=            # Assert that it's possible to match this after the current position:
 .*            # any number of characters, followed by
 \bChapter 2\b # the text "Chapter 2"
)              # End of lookahead assertion.
```

Comment: Beautiful! It was the "followed by any number of characters" bit that was eluding me. Thank you for the detailed explanation!